# CSS configuration on Wordpress <PDF Online viewer how to disable the download button>

Tags: css, wordpress

Here is a shot of the button that i want to remove with `margin-top: 20px;` for example

[Dev toolsImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2sU4.png)

On the backend page editor i am editing this styles but is not affected.
[Backend Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxIek.png)

the pdf is [this](http://kalantzakis-lures.gr/companies/zerek-2/)

how to disable the download button ??

The plugin that iam using has only a php file

Comment: Have you tried visibility:hidden; or display:none; ?

Comment: The changes is not affected...i am using the same classes as i see on devtools

Are you thinking a new way to select this img... ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pdf load in `iframe` that's why previous css not working. You should try jquery. Basically, you just append a `style` element to the `head` of the inner iframe.

```
$('iframe').load( function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find("head")
      .append($("<style type='text/css'>  .flowpaper_bttnDownload{display:none !important;}  </style>"));
});
```

Comment: in your wp theme. Do you have any js file? which is include in your theme.

Comment: I can't find any custom js file from this theme .

Comment: okay, Add this script into the footer section. Edit footer.php file and add this script inside the $(document).redy(function(){......});

Comment: Not working..it'ok i will find another plugin and maybe i can tweak some css here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you used any WP plugin for showing PDF then check first have any option to disable download button in your plugin. Otherwise you can try below CSS

```
 .flowpaper_bttnDownload{
      display: none !important;
  }
```

Comment: Its a plugin ..

and has only a php file.

I have no idea about php

Comment: Add the above to the style.css file in your theme. Appearance > Editor > > Select your theme in the dropdown > Style.css. And add it below any other code. @D.Tsiridakis

Comment: did you add css in style.css file? What happened after add css